# Help with Cisco Wireless LAN Controller CLI Flexconnect configurations

Tags: cli, cisco-wlc

Having transitioned into a full time Python programmer and automation architect, I've sadly lost a lot of hands on experience.

I'm currently working with a customer to configure 20 Cisco 8510 controllers and reconfiguring the setup to Flexconnect mode on all access points. Before that, creating the proper groups, which will reflect the location identification numbers.

Question: Are there any commands, where you need to confirm the action, by entering 'y' for yes, for instance, if an access point restarts or something similar?
I just cannot remember this anymore.

All commands below are utilized directly on the WLC CLI.

Group creation commands:

```
config flexconnect group 7775-flex add
config flexconnect group 7775-flex vlan enable
config flexconnect group 7775-flex vlan native 124
config flexconnect group 7775-flex vlan override enable
config flexconnect group 7775-flex wlan-vlan wlan 19 vlan 109
config flexconnect group 7775-flex wlan-vlan wlan 24 vlan 199
```

Access Point commands:

```
config ap name 7143-A06 bc:26:c7:18:9c:4a
config mode ap flexconnect submode none 7143-A06
config flexconnect ap 7143-flex add bc:26:c7:18:9c:4a
config ap group-name Hotspot 7143-A06
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration commands don't require confirmation.  File manipulation commands (Save, Copy, Delete) or OS commands (Reload, Boot) do --that includes commands that will reboot an AP.

P.S.  Welcome back!